# Have user continue to run test in step load after x amount of users have ramped up (python) (locust)

Tags: python-3.x, locust

My use case is as below: I am trying to run a test programmatically where in i want users to ramp up to a certain amount of users. Then once the ramp up is finished i want the combined ramped up users to continue the test for an hour.

Below is the code, by which i can have users (5 in total) ramp up until time_limit (300) is reached. Now i want to have these users run for an hour after the ramping up has finished. Any suggestions what changes i need to make to the code?

```
import math
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task, constant
from locust import LoadTestShape

class StepLoadShape(LoadTestShape):
    """
    A step load shape


    Keyword arguments:

        step_time -- Time between steps
        step_load -- User increase amount at each step
        spawn_rate -- Users to stop/start per second at every step
        time_limit -- Time limit in seconds

    """
    # this below config led to 5 users in total
    step_time = 60
    step_load = 1
    spawn_rate = 1
    time_limit = 300

    def tick(self):
        run_time = self.get_run_time()

        if run_time > self.time_limit:
            return None

        current_step = math.floor(run_time / self.step_time) + 1
        return (current_step * self.step_load, self.spawn_rate)

class UserBehavior(HttpUser):
    wait_time=constant(1)
    host="https://google.com"

    @task
    def launch_URL(self):
        token = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

        headers={
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization":"Bearer " + token,
        "id":"TEST_QA"}

        with self.client.get("/google.com?clientId=test&userId=user_1",headers=headers,catch_response=True) as response:
            if ("Descriptor") in response.json():
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    response.success()
                else:
                    response.failure("HTTP 200OK not received")
            else:
                response.failure("Valid response not returned")
```

Comment: You already have those parameters in place I think : http://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html

So, run time = 1h, users = 5, spawn rate = you can define the users/second

Comment: @DevangSanghani passing the run time param with this class throws an error

Comment: Running it in headless mode?

Comment: @DevangSanghani fixed that, now the issue is that its throwing below error on the response.json() block . `Error: [2022-02-08 21:48:28,739] xxxxx.internal/ERROR/locust.user.task: [Errno Expecting value] : 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 910, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 393, in raw_decode
return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: Seems like your `response.json()` is empty. Is that the url you are testing against? I would always first place `if response.status_code == 200:` right after getting a response and then check the contents of the response.

Comment: Yes i am checking that and did replace that with response.text() and that fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am checking that and did replace that with response.text() and that fixed it. Thanks!